# Unique id number C#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to store some sales transactions in Isolated Storage in a "offline" silverlight oob application. 
I was thinking about generating a unique number to track which transaction is which using DateTime.Now.Ticks.

Is this a good idea?

thanks in advance for the answers. I know this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public string generateUniqueID()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
}
```

Check [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)

> Represents a globally unique identifier (GUID).
>
> **Remarks:**
>
> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all
>   computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such
>   an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good idea?

No, it is not a good idea.

Because [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) represents local time on computer. That means if any change on your local time in your server (change by hand, any crash on server effects local time, Daylight saving time etc.), your code *might* (it is a small probability but..) generates same id values.

As ohters suggested, [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) will be a good choice about generating a unique values. There is no guarantee to get %100 on GUID. But it is like %99.999999999999999999999. That's why the collision probability is *very very* small.

From Wikipedia page;

> **While each generated GUID is not guaranteed to be unique**, the total
>   number of unique keys (2^128 or 3.4×10^38) is so large that the
>   probability of the same number being generated twice is very small.
>   For example, consider the observable universe, which contains about
>   5×10^22 stars; every star could then have 6.8×10^15 universally unique
>   GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a GUID?

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: I forgot! Silly me... tunnel vision gets me

Answer (score 0):

```
private string generateUniqueID(int size) //recieves the size of the wanted hex ID
{
    bool done = true;
    string n_id = "";


    while (!done)
    {
        done = true;
        while (n_id.Length < size + 1)
            n_id += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(new Random().Next(48, 90));

        foreach (Transaction i in tns) //I used this for each to check if the generated ID already exists, you can use an external function.
        {
            if (i.ID == n_id)
            {
                done = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return n_id;
}
```